# Populate a view model with a data model with a method aswell

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq-to-sql

i need to populate my articles ViewModel with a model that has the database data in it, but i have a method that i need to assign to one of my properties

The list of images is the property that needs the method on it.
The method is called once for every item in the list of articles.

Here is my code:

```
        public ActionResult ArticleTypes(string at)
        {
            articleViewModel.Images = new List<ImageInfo>();
            var query = (from a in db.Articles
                         where a.SelectedArticleType == at
                         select new ArticlesViewModel
                         {
                             Id = a.Id,
                             Body = a.Body,
                             Headline = a.Headline,
                             PostedDate = a.PostedDate,
                             SelectedArticleType = a.SelectedArticleType,
                             UserName = a.UserName,


                         }).ToList();
            articleViewModel.Images = imageService.GetImagesForArticle(articlemodel.Id.ToString());


            return View(query);
    }
```

I have also tried putting the method inside the linq:

```
public ActionResult ArticleTypes(string at)
    {
        articleViewModel.Images = new List<ImageInfo>();
        var query = (from a in db.Articles
                     where a.SelectedArticleType == at
                     select new ArticlesViewModel
                     {
                         Id = a.Id,
                         Body = a.Body,
                         Headline = a.Headline,
                         PostedDate = a.PostedDate,
                         SelectedArticleType = a.SelectedArticleType,
                         UserName = a.UserName,
                         Images = imageService.GetImagesForArticle(a.Id.ToString())
                     }).ToList();



        return View(query);
}
```

it throws an exception of:
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[New_MinecraftNews_Webiste_MVC.Models.ImageInfo] GetImagesForArticle

Comment: You want to display list of images in the view?

Comment: I still didnt understand the question well. Did you mean that you need to call imageService.GetImagesForArticle(id) everytime you create an ArticlesViewModel?

Comment: in one view i want to display a list of images e.g. the page of the article and on the other i want the first image @Reddy

Comment: @SwagataPrateek it is called for every item in the list of articles

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: Oh ok thank you for telling me this

Answer (score 0):

I added a foreach loop at the end insted of anything else and it works:

```
    public ActionResult ArticleTypes(string at)
    {
        articleViewModel.Images = new List<ImageInfo>();
        var modelList = (from a in db.Articles
                     where a.SelectedArticleType == at
                     select new ArticlesViewModel
                     {
                         Id = a.Id,
                         Body = a.Body,
                         Headline = a.Headline,
                         PostedDate = a.PostedDate,
                         SelectedArticleType = a.SelectedArticleType,
                         UserName = a.UserName
                     }).ToList();


        foreach (var model in modelList)
        {
            model.Images = imageService.GetImagesForArticle(model.Id.ToString());
        }


        return View(modelList);
}
```